# Are there any other parameters that can be sent in the Postgresql connection other than ApplicationName, that act like ApplicationName?

Tags: postgresql

Switching from DB2 to Postgresql.

I'm looking for some connection parameters to pass some strings into, that can actually be retrieved from within a Trigger Function.

DB2 has connection parameters:

- ApplicationName,
- ClientUser,
- ClientAccountingInformation

Postgresql has connection parameters:

- ApplicationName   (max 64 characters)

I tried setting Transaction Level session variable using `select set_config('<param_name>', '<param_value>', true)` in a connection interceptor. This seems to work most of the time, but occasionally the parameter doesn't get passed; making it unreliable.

So I'm back to trying to pass Connection parameters.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A session variable set via `set_config()` or `SET` syntax is the way to go. What exactly did you find to be unreliable, could you reproduce the problem?

Comment: From my understanding, the `application_name` parameter set for the connection is just the same kind of [configuration variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html) as session-level variables.

Comment: The Postgres JDBC driver [only runs](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/8825a38f7ce33667b5568e5f1a4d086ef06e0457/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java#L863) `set application_name = ...` during connect which is the same as calling `set_config()` so I don't see why this should be unreliable. Note that this is transactional, so if you turned off autocommit and then did a `rollback()` later, this resets the configuration property.